# Slice list in loop by step

Tags: python, loops, slice

looking for a nice way to solve slice problem.

```py
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
step = 5
```

```py
print -> [1,2,3,4,5]
print -> [6,7,8,9,10]
print -> [11]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What is your goal and what have you tried?

Comment: So you want to divide a list into small ones based on a size?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
output = [list_a[i:i + step] for i in range(0, len(list_a), step)]
```

When you pass:

```
list_a = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
```

You will get like this:

```
output = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['10']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use slice notation: `list_a[:step]`. With try and except:
`try:  print(list_a[:step]) except: print('Out of Range')`

Comment: Remember the first `:` is for the slice, the second is step. So `list_a[slice_start:slice_end:step]`

Comment: How avoid -> out of range?

Comment: Use try and accept.

Comment: It not rally nice way.